# Airflow webserver not filtering Dags by owner

Tags: airflow

I'm attempting to filter Dags by owner in my Airflow instance.
List of the steps i'm taking.

> 1- Configure my airflow.cfg  as follow. [portion of airflow.cfg config
>   file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSe3c.png)
>
> 2- My Dags receive a owner through default_args variable
>
> 3- Have an Airflow user named as the one pass to my Dags as owner

Still when I login with the user, I can see all Dags. Steps to create [the user](https://airflow.apache.org/security.html#web-authentication)

Any Idea Why is not filtering Dags by owner. Thanks

Comment: This site is for programming questions. This question is off topic. You need to post on server fault. That's a much better fit.

Comment: Thank you. I've posted on server fault as well.

Comment: No problem. I'm surprised you didn't get flamed yet.

Answer (score 2):

**Until Airflow Version 1.9.0**:

The reason the user is still able to access all the dags is that it is a `superuser` by default. Unless you use LDAP for authentication, all the users created are superusers and Airflow have no other roles.

However, if you use LDAP, you can have superuser and dataprofiler roles.

This should change in upcoming versions of Airflow.